# Why headers sent error occur in action in controller in yii2?

Tags: php, controller, yii2, action

There is an error saying, headers are already sent, showing that print_r occuring the error, but in tutorial the print_r's array appears before navbar at the top of web page

```
class PostController extends AppController
{
    public function actionTest()
    {
        $names = ['Ivanov', 'Petrov', 'Sidorov'];

        print_r($names);

        return $this->render('test');
    }

}
```

Comment: you are trying to output some data before header redirection. that's cause the issue. remove `print_r($names);` and you will good to go

Comment: Whenever you want to check/print your data (for testing purpose) you should put a `die();` before rendering the view.

Comment: @Gru `die()` will break framework flow - you should avoid using `echo`/`print_r` in the first place.

Comment: welll if i have to check an `array` or `data` i would `print_r();` and then `return;` the next line.

Answer (score 1):

YOu shuold not output values  with echo, print_r or var_dump .. before return

```
class PostController extends AppController
{
  public function actionTest()
  {
    $names = ['Ivanov', 'Petrov', 'Sidorov'];


    return $this->render('test');
  }

}
```

in your case remove  `print_r($names);`